# Example of semi-algebras that are not algebras

Tags: measure-theory

I know that every algebra is as semi-algebra, and the book (A course in Real Analysis, McDonald and Weiss) tells me that the opposite is not true: not every semi-algebra is an algebra. Why not?

A semi-algebra contains all finite intersections of its members. This satisfies the condition that an algebra must contain all finite intersection (or unions).

So I think the problem is with the complement-condition:

- If the complement to a member in the semi-algebra is $\emptyset$,
  then this satisfies some of the condition to be an algebra (that
  every complement must be in the algebra).
- So I guess that something goes wrong with the complement being a
  finite union of pairwise disjoint sets? But I don´t know why?

Do anyone have an example of semi-algebras that are not algebras?

Comment: For discussion and examples, see also https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/definition-of-a-semialgebra.334682/.

Comment: statement "every semi-algebra is not an algebra" is not true, and "not every semi-algebra is an algebra" is a true statement.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\mathcal{C}=\{\Omega,\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ then $\mathcal{C}$ is a semi-algebra but NOT an algebra.

Answer (score 3):

The collection of half-open intervals $[a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a semialgebra, but not an algebra, since the complement of $[a,b)$ is $(\infty,a)\cup [b,\infty)$, which is not a half open interval.

**Edit:** In order for what I said to be a semialgebra, you need to allow $a,b$ to be $\infty$, and $[\infty,b)$ is interpreted to be $(\infty, b)$.

Comment: Hmm, I started to think about this. Why is the complement in the semi-algebra then?

Comment: The complement is not in the semi-algebra. A semi-algebra is not closed under complements, but if $S$ in the semi-algebra, then $S^c$ is a finite disjoint union of elements in the semi-algebra. The half open intervals work because the complement of $[a,b)$ is the disjoint union of $(\infty,a)$ and $[b,\infty)$, which are both in the semi-algebra (I've edited my post to clarify you need to allow $a,b$ to be $\infty$ for this to works).